# Find closest matching word from set of words with custom logic

Tags: java, angular, search

I have two list, each having set of attributes name, I want to map attribute names from first list to seconds list. First list is the standard list of attributes which is fixed, but the attributes name in second list varies. There may be a TYPO, short form used etc. for attribute name which should map to some attribute in first list.

These lists are not huge, it has around 30-40 attributes each.

I was looking for the solution & found that there are many algorithm to find distance & matching words(s) for e.g. Levenstein.

Unfortunately it does not cover scenarios like

- abbreviations like "DOB" and "Date of Birth" is same.
- Different attribute name but it represent same information, For e.g. "Date of Birth" "Age".

Is there way to train or give hints to these algorithm so that it covers such scenarios as well.

Atul

Comment: Even with sophisticated, specialized (expensive!) master data management (MDM) matching tools, there is almost always the need for some manual intervention, e.g. to maintain lists of synonyms (`DOB` and `data of birth`) or to resolve ambiguous matches.

Comment: A middle ground between simple distance matching (as noted in your question) and industrial-strength tools could be to manage your own specific and smaller data set yourself, using multiple strategies. A library such as Lucene can help you to do this (levenshtein; synonyms; ngrams; etc.). [Some related notes here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55324306/12567365)